# updating two mysql columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script which searches database and dispays the list of users whose attendance are to be marked by their supervisor. Supervisor marks attendance and fills remarks and submits the form.

I am able to insert attendance in mysql database but remarks column is not being  updated.

Pls Guide.

Form script

```
<td id="present">
<input type="radio" name="present[<? echo $rows['id']; ?>]" checked="checked"     value="P">P
</td>
<td id="absent">
<input type="radio" name="present[<? echo $rows['id']; ?>]" value="A">A
</td>
<td id="tour">
<input type="radio" name="present[<? echo $rows['id']; ?>]" value="T">T
</td>
<td id="leave">
<input type="radio" name="present[<? echo $rows['id']; ?>]" value="L">L
</td>
</td>
<td id="hpl">
<input type="radio" name="present[<? echo $rows['id']; ?>]" value="H">H
</td>
<td width="30%" id="remark">
<input type="text" name="remark[]" />
</td>
</tr>
<?php  }?>
<?php  }?>
<tr>
<td colspan="7" style="vertical-align:middle; text-align: center;"><br><br>
<input id="Submit" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Mark Attendance" style="text-    align: center; background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff; border: 1px #000000 solid;">
</td>
```

and mysql update script

```
foreach($_POST['present'] as $id => $value)
                   {
                         $getSets = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE     id='".$id."'");
$ausers = mysql_fetch_array($getSets);
$class=$ausers['user'];
$section=$ausers['email'];
$branch=$ausers['branch'];
$date1=$_POST['date'];
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date1));
$sql = "INSERT INTO statistics(user, wquestions, date, att, marker, branch, remark) VALUES ('$class', '$section', '$date', '".$value."','".USERNAME."', '$branch', '".$remark."') ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Try removing the `[]` in `name="remark[]"` as `name="remark"` - this shouldn't be used if it's not an array. It seems to be a single input and not a multiple.

Comment: No its a multiple input . every user has got their separate attendance and separate remarks. pls guide

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, your script doesn't handle data from `$_POST['remark']`. You are only handling the `$_POST['present']` part of your POST. Remember that each input's name directly corresponds to the POST's array index when it is sent.
To easier visualize what you are posting and how the data is sent through, you can do:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

Based off your code, the "remark" is an array. Brackets in name `[ ]` you would need something like:

```
foreach ($_POST['remark'] as $k => $r) {
   // Insert the remark data
}
```

Otherwise, if there is only 1 remark it should be renamed "remark" without the `[ ]`.

Comment: I have tried but i am unable to handle two arrays. I had done like this>>>>          foreach($_POST['present'] as $id => $value)
foreach($_POST['remark'] as $id => $value1){ insert in database} but it inserts first accourding to present array and then through remark array . as a result data is multiplied

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit ur INSERT query as:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO statistics(user, wquestions, date, att, marker, branch, remark)   VALUES ('$class', '$section', '$date', '".$value."','".USERNAME."', '$branch', '".$_POST['remark']."')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```